# Unbounded Local Error Python

Tags: python, exception, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prpR.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "prpR.py", line 39, in main
    d=drop()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'drop' referenced.
```

It is something to do with the scope of the drop() in that when I all main() the drop() only exists in that scope. I have tried messing around with a global variable to fill the rain_drops array but I can't seem to get this error to go away. Also style comments would be much appreciated. Code is below.

```
 from graphics import *
from random import randint
#(137,43,226)
#(229,230,250) -BG

#d=None
class drop:
    dc = color_rgb(136,43,226)
    win=GraphWin("Purple Rain-Prince", 498, 500, autoflush=False)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(228,230,250))
    win.setCoords(0,0,1000,1000)    
    lwr=6 #length to width ratio length:width
    def __init__(self):
        x= randint(0,1000)
        self.diff=randint(-1,10)        
        y=randint(0,1000)
        p1= Point(x, y)
        p2=Point(x+self.diff,y+drop.lwr*self.diff)
        self.r=Rectangle(p-1, p2)
        self.r.setFill( color_rgb(136,43,226))
        self.r.draw(drop.win)
    def reset(self):
        x= randint(0,1000)
        self.diff=randint(1,20)         
        y=998
        p1= Point(x, y)
        p0=Point(x+self.diff,y+drop.lwr*self.diff)
        self.r.undraw()
        self.r=Rectangle(p1, p2)
        self.r.setFill( color_rgb(136,43,226))
        self.r.draw(drop.win)
    def fall(self):
        self.r.move(0,-self.diff)   
        if self.r.getP0().getY()<5:
            self.reset()

def main():
    d=drop()
    rain_drops=[drop() for i in range(38)]
    while(drop.win.checkMouse()==None):
        for drop in rain_drops:
            drop.fall()
        update(28)
    drop.win.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that `drop` is used as a local variable later in your function. This `for` statement does the dirty work:

```
for drop in rain_drops:
```

On each pass of the loop, this binds `drop` as a local variable to an instance from the list you're loop over (shadowing the class name `drop` which is a global variable). When a name is used as a local variable in a function you can't access a global of the same name at any point in the function (the compiler assumes you're doing things out of order, like `print(foo); foo="bar"` if `foo` didn't exist previously).

Probably the best fix for this issue would be to rename your class to `Drop`, in keeping with [Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) that says that most classes should have `CapWords` style names. That way you wouldn't have a name conflict betweeen `Drop` (the class) and `drop` (an instance you access as you're looping).

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a happy Holiday!